# Error loading the system

Tags: dual-boot, plymouth, error

After the some updates were installed, the top and bottom bar didn't appear. I decided to shutdown the computer to see if it was solved and then I get that error. I could manage to access the terminal but there's no internet connection and the visual interfaces don't load.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal to remove qemu-kvm:

```
sudo apt-get purge qemu-system-common
```

Then type to restart:

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```

If you do not want to remove qemu-kvm then type :

```
sudo systemctl stop qemu-kvm
```

Then type:

```
sudo systemctl disable qemu-kvm
```

Then type :

```
sudo systemctl mask qemu-kvm
```

Check status of qemu-kvm:

```
sudo systemctl status qemu-kvm
```

To restart:

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```